# Is it possible to return a list of all ranges from all worksheets in an Excel 2002 workbook?

Tags: list, range, excel-2002

I want to extract "special" data from an Excel 2002 (client requirement, cannot change) workbook and worksheets contained therein.  I have classified ranges in this "special" data category.  I would like to acquire a list of all ranges in, ideally, all worksheets in a workbook.  The attributes I'm interested in are the range name, and the range address.  I have been googling for a while now, and have not found anything relevant.

I was assuming the Excel 2002 API would expose something like this:

```
ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\file.xls", ...);
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["sheet1"] as Worksheet;
Range[] ranges = worksheet.GetAllRanges();
```

or something similar.  However, I am sadly mistaken.

Is this possible with Excel 2002?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for all the ranges that are Named you should look at the Workbook.Names collection.
Each Name in the Names collection has a RefersTo property that gives the Formula or Range Reference that is referenced by the Name.
(But be aware that a Name can be a Formula rather than a Range Reference)


Dim oNM as Name

for each oNM in ActiveWorkbook.Names
debug.print oNM.Refersto
next oNM